# Python one liner with function

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am strengthening my understanding of one liner in Python and have some difficulties for the following one. I would like to use list comprehension to make it shorter. Any contribution would be great please.

```
daily_prices_l = []
daily_prices_h = []
for b in bitwise_exchanges:
  try:
    high = daily_OHLCV('BTC', 'USD', exchange=b).set_index('timestamp').high
    low = daily_OHLCV('BTC', 'USD', exchange=b).set_index('timestamp').low
    daily_prices_l.append(high.rename(b))
    daily_prices_h.append(low.rename(b))
  except:
    pass
daily_prices_l = pd.concat(daily_prices_l, axis=1)
daily_prices_h = pd.concat(daily_prices_h, axis=1)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "one liner"? Why are you wrapping everything in a bare `try-except`???

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I mean list comprehension. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: I'd recommend staying away from dot notation for column references.  Use ['high'] and ['low'] instead of .low and .high.

Comment: @ScottBoston thank you. Could you explain why please?

Comment: @MafPipo The dot notation is a shortcut, but it has limitations and can not be use when column headers have spaces, special characters, or the column name is a reserved word like 'count'. To avoid such confusion, I say just avoid use the dot notation all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
daily_prices_l = pd.concat([daily_OHLCV('BTC', 'USD', exchange=b).set_index('timestamp').low.rename(b) for b in bitwise_exchanges], axis=1)
daily_prices_h = pd.concat([daily_OHLCV('BTC', 'USD', exchange=b).set_index('timestamp').high.rename(b) for b in bitwise_exchanges], axis=1)
```

Comment: This is not a criticism of your answer but I think it bears mentioning anyway.  There is a performance hit since this loops over `bitwise_exchanges` twice instead of once.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty unnecessary, taking that it is hard to read, but here is a way:

```
try: daily_prices_l,daily_prices_h = pd.concat([daily_OHLCV('BTC', 'USD', exchange=b).set_index('timestamp').high.rename(b) for b in bitwise_exchanges],axis=1),pd.concat([daily_OHLCV('BTC', 'USD', exchange=b).set_index('timestamp').low.rename(b) for b in bitwise_exchanges],axis=1)
except: pass
```

Comment: thanks, my understanding is that the error handling does not handle by iteration of the loop which is not good since it skips all the data when some data may exist. Is that correct please?

Comment: When I said hard to read, I meant my answer. Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Does the answer you're looking for have to include the error handling, or can we just skip it?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have to keep the error handling. But need to handle by iteration of loop, which look complicated?